# Remove text from Google documents by apps script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, http-post, google-docs

I write an invoice printing script in GAS with data from Woocommerce (a post request). The script is triggered when the post request comes. I place a word acting as a placeholder ("#product") to insert a table of product data. After everything done, i want to remove the word but its not working. (the invoice is created but "#product" still stays in the invoice document)

But it was running when I triggered the script myself (it works by manual run - "#product" is removed). I cant figure out the reason. Pls help!
Here is the script:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  //Woocommerce Webhook sends order info 
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
   //my code
   var templateID = "template ID"
   var documentID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID).makeCopy().getId(); //Drive API
   var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
   // find "#product" => insert table => loop throug array => appendTableCell
        var insert = body.findText('#product');  //#product - placeholder
        var point = insert.getElement();    
        var parent = point.getParent();
        var index = parent.getParent().getChildIndex(parent); //get location index => insert product data table at this location 
        var table = body.insertTable(index);
        var header = table.appendTableRow();
        header.appendTableCell("smt");
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                  var row = table.appendTableRow();
                      row.appendTableCell("smt");
                      row.appendTableCell("smt");
                      }  
        body.findText("#product").getElement().removeFromParent(); //clear #product => this code not working with automatic trigger by post request
        }
```

Comment: The Stack Snippet should be used only for HTML/JavaScript/CSS that could be executed on this page. By the other hand, the closing `}` for `doPost is missing`. Is there something else that is missing too?

Comment: View>stackdriver  errors?

Comment: Have you published your script as a web app?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the difference between `I triggered the script myself` and `it works by manual run`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Tanaike I mean: its the same (manual run = trigger the script myself). The error only occurs if the script run automatically. When i remove the code to trigger the script by post request (the new code starts from "var templateID = "template ID" ", the script can run completely and also remove "#product" in the final document.

Comment: @Rubén: its my typing mistake. In GAS, I added all necessary tag & already pubished it as a web app.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, when you run `doPost` by requesting with the POST method, the script doesn't work. But when you directly run `doPost` with the script editor by removing the line of `var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents])`, the script worked. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @TheMaster: there s nothing in the stackdriver log. Maybe I havent updated the project to the standard project to utilize the stackdriver log.

Comment: @Tanaike No, i need to remove the code related to post request including "var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents])" to make the script run.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `i need to remove the code related to post request including "var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents])" to make the script run.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I mean my new code is below: function myFunction() {var templateID = "template ID"....}.

Comment: View>executions? Failed ?

Comment: @TheMaster Nope, it has "completed" status. But in the final document, "#product" still remains.

Comment: What is the use of `myData`?

Comment: @TheMaster Sorry, for all executions automatically, the status are "failed". "myData" is a post request from Woocommerce webhook. Woocommerce sends the order info to trigger the script. The script prints the invoice and finally remove the word "#product" in the result document. But til now, the script failed to remove "#product"

Comment: 1.`myData`isn't used at all in your script. You declared it. Then nothing. 2. If you click "Failed", error should show.

Comment: Finally i upgraded my project to a standard GCP and used stackdriver logging to know the failure reason. MakeCopy() is the reason of the failure (i used it to create a new file in a shared drive). Im finding a workaround solution. Thanks all for your support!